# Plotly marker size

Tags: r, plotly

I am having trouble getting the plotly marker size to work correctly.

```
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,5,3,4,2,6,4,5),
                   b = c(12,14,11,10,3,7,5,8,15,2),
                   c = c("d","e","d","f","e","d","f","e","e","f"),
                   d = c(5,5,10,15,10,15,5,10,5,15))
```

```
plot_ly()%>%
add_trace(data = test, x = ~a, y = ~b, mode = 'markers', type = 'scatter',
          color = ~c, colors = c("red", "blue", "green"),
          marker = list(size = ~d), text = ~d, hoverinfo = 'text')
```

I added a text box with the column that is supposed to be used as the marker size and it works correctly, so any help with what is going wrong with the size would be appreciated.

Comment: I get the different sizes as well, they just do not match the number in column d.  If you scroll over the points and see the text, some of the "15" points are the size of the "5" points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps, where sizes are defined by `d`:

```
test <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,5,3,4,2,6,4,5),
                   b = c(12,14,11,10,3,7,5,8,15,2),
                   c = c("d","e","d","f","e","d","f","e","e","f"),
                   d = c(5,5,10,15,10,15,5,10,5,15))
plot_ly()%>%
  add_trace(data = test, x = ~a, y = ~b, mode = 'markers', type = 'scatter',
            color = ~c, colors = c("red", "blue", "green"),
            size = ~d, text = ~d, hoverinfo = 'text')
```